# Make yaourt does not reinstall when already installed

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, yaourt

Is there a way to make yaourt does not reinstall when the package (from AUR) already installed

```
 $ yaourt -Q jruby
 local/jruby 1.7.3-1
```

but somehow

```
 $ yaourt --needed --noconfirm -S jruby
```

keep redownload (even if it has been downloaded before) and reinstall jruby

Comment: You shouldn't, as PKGBUILD can be out dated at anytime.

Comment: but it doesn't even updating, the installed version is exactly the same as to be downloaded one

Comment: If pkgver+pkgrel+pkgname are unchanged, it's useless to reinstall

Comment: yes i know, and i do not want to reinstall, i just want it to install when not installed and reinstall when it's already installed but has an update, but yaourt keep reinstalling when the package is from AUR even when there is no new update

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution can be made with a simple script:

1. Open file

   ```
   $ vim yaourt-helper.sh
   ```
2. Create script

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash
   _update="yaourt -Syua --noconfirm"
   if ! which $1 2>/dev/null 1>&2; then
      echo 'Package not installed, installing'
      $_update $1
      exit $?;
   fi
   echo 'Already installed, checking for upgrade'
   $_update
   ```
3. Set permissions and execute

`$ chmod +x yaourt-helper.sh && ./yaourt-helper.sh jruby`

Note: using `--noconfirm` is dangerous unless your know exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using **$@** instead of **$1** in ***@anonimal's*** script. it would let to check all packages sent to script one-by-one